# Dependency property populated with Binding object?

Tags: c#, uwp

How come that the following populates my dependency property with a "Binding" object instead of a string value?

```
<local:CustomButton MyText="{Binding Name}" />
```

It works with normal buttons.

This is how I register my buttons properties:

```
public static DependencyProperty RegisterProperty(string propertyName) {
    return DependencyProperty.Register(propertyName, typeof(object), typeof(ButtonHD), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

The rest is just normal boilerplate code. Why am I getting a Binding object when binding the name to MyText? I mean it works with normal buttons which means the binding is fine. This is extremely weird.

Full implementation of my user control:

```
public sealed partial class CustomButton : UserControl {
    public object MyText {
        get { return GetValue(MyTextDependency); }
        set { SetValue(MyTextDependency, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextDependency = RegisterProperty(nameof(MyText));

    public CustomButton() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Render(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs e) {
      var test = MyText;
      // The below fails:
      string test = (string) MyText;
    }

    public static DependencyProperty RegisterProperty(string propertyName) {
        return DependencyProperty.Register(propertyName, typeof(object), typeof(CustomButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    }
}
```

and here my XAML:

```
<Canvas:CanvasControl Background="Transparent" Draw="Render">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerReleased">
            <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Canvas:CanvasControl>
```

Comment: How did you read the property and got Binding object? Have you used the `MyText.get` getter, or was it some fancy thing like `ReadLocalValue`?

Comment: Total wild guess:In VS, check F4/Properties on that .xaml file and see what Build-Action is, and compare to other xaml files that work properly. There could be something like it's not configured to be a View/Control/Page/etc but as  some more exotic component type like resourcedictionary/etc where {Binding} are not supported and XAML works just like IoCC and simply instantiates obejcts and sets properties. Another total wild guess: check .xaml file of that ButtonHD/CustomButton and see if the root tag matches the `:baseclass` (UserControl) - it has to match perfectly,with prefix/namespace/etc.

Comment: ^above guesses are made basing on observation that your code seems fine, so unless you do something totally weird elsewhere, it seems that either the XAML compiler does not compile the XAML properly (i.e. it does `this.MyText = new Binding` instead of `this.SetBinding(MyTextProperty, new Binding`)`, OR the base class somehow does not support DependencyProperties/and/or bindings and they treat it as normal value object.

Comment: Are you getting any System.Data.Error in output in VisualStudio?

Comment: @sTrenat note just: Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding' to type 'System.String'.'

Comment: @quetzalcoatl this sucks. I could maybe try using a converter or something

Comment: Try with path=name, or just declare type as string, not object

Comment: And one question, did you do something like: DataContext = this, in your userControl?

Comment: @sTrenat could try that. might be the culprit.

Comment: @sTrenat oh no. I wouldnt bind to itself .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154383/discussion-between-asperger-and-strenat).

Comment: I'm just asking, that's sometimes issue. I'll check your code in 30min and will try to recreate issue. Do you use MyText somewhere else?

Comment: Nope, the text is only uses within the control itself. That is, inside the draw event handler which is triggered the moment the control is created.

Comment: That's what i mean. Try with adding default value for MyText, like "", or something

Comment: @sTrenat I can make a bounty for you! Id like to give you 300 points for giving me the advice  : )

Comment: I don't know how it works, but i think you can :) let me just write answer.

Comment: @Asperger, All you had to do for this question was to wait the 2 days it takes for this question to become eligible for a bounty and then you would have been able to start the bounty to reward what you considered to be a very helpful answer. It is one of the provided reasons when creating a bounty. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you'r using your MyText somewhere beside, there is chance that your object is empty when it's check, there is no string inside, instead, there is Binding expression. 
You could assign some default value, and add some action on DependencyPropertyChanged, and validate where is the fault. 
Sample:

```
var metadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( "", OnValueChanged, null, null)
return DependencyProperty.Register(propertyName, typeof(object), 
                                   typeof(CustomButton), metadata)

private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  ;
}
```